# Change the div height dynamically on expan/collapse of details tag in HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a set of details tag within a container whose height is set dynamically to fit the screen size. Whenever I expand the details tag and when the content height is greater than screen, container styles are not getting applied. I have attached a screenshot for better understanding:

[image]

```
<div class="container" style"background-color:blue;">
<details>
  <summary>Copyright 1999-2014.</summary>
  <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Copyright 1999-2014.</summary>
 .............................
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Copyright 1999-2014.</summary>
  .............................
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Copyright 1999-2014.</summary>
  .............................
<details>
  <summary>Copyright 1999-2014.</summary>
  .............................
</details>
</div>
```

JQuery to set the height to fit screen:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.container').css('height', $(window).height());
        // Comma, not colon ----^
    }
);

$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.container').css('height', $(window).height());
    // Comma, not colon ----^
});
```

Comment: you froget to add `px` after setting the heigth

Comment: First of all style attribute doesn't have the equals ('=') sign: `<div class="container" style="background-color:blue;">`. Also second to last `<details>` tag is not closed. Please fix and change the example to a snippet. I've tried to reproduce and the whole page was blue, so I'm not sure where the error is.